# Django using a newly create object in reverse redirect

Tags: django, forms, reverse, modelform

I am trying to pull the id from the newly created project object so I can redirect the user to the page containing the new project. Right now I get "'ProjectAddForm' object has no attribute 'id'".

I have read online that this should work but for some reason it's not.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProjectAddForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('project.views.detail', args=(form.id)))
```

Forms.py

```
class ProjectAddForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Project
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `save` method returns your model object.  Grab a reference to it and then you will have the 'id' you need for your reverse redirect.

```
instance = form.save()
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('project.views.detail', instance.id))
```

Comment: Ahh that did it and makes total sense. Only thing I had to do is add a , after the reverse instance.id and it works. Thanks!